# RSelenium Get Text Element offscreen

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape information about football manager with RSelenium. I've got that $findElements found all elements that I want, but I see that when i execute $getElementText for each element, RSelenium only give me the data that is in the screen's navigator.

This is the web code:

[image]
[image]

And my code at R is this:

```
#---------take the player's name and value---------

pvp <- remote_driver$findElements(using = 'xpath', value = '//* [@id="pressReleases"]/ul/li/ul/li/span')
price<- sapply(pvp, function(x) x$getElementText())

naming<- remote_driver$findElements(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="pressReleases"]/ul/li/ul/li/strong')
name <- sapply(naming, function(x) x$getElementText())
```

For each attribute RSelenium found 150 of each, that's correct.

[image]

But when I see 'name' and 'price' there aren't 150 values, only the values that are active in the screen's navigator.

For example Name:

[image]

For example Price:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to get all the 150 values?

Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: Because of the laziness of the application.However you need to scroll the each element and then only you will be able to get the value.

Comment: thanks @KunduK At the end i did remote_driver$getPageSource() and then used rvest